# USB Soundcard cant record Sound

Tags: raspbian

The Problem is: i cant record sound with my USB soundcard microphone.

When i try:

```
rec test.wav
```

I only recive:

```
rec FAIL formats: can't open input  `default': snd_pcm_open error: No such file    or directory
```

And this works:

```
AUDIODEV=hw:0 rec test.wav trim 0 5
```

this is my sound debug

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=9b394146e59fccf0209771190c9660a53c316144